# Prove $EB=EC$ and that $F,M,G,C$ are concyclic in the given figure

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, quadrilateral

Given is a quadrilateral $ABCD$ in which $\angle DAB=\angle CDA=90$. Point M is the midpoint of side $BC$ and circumscribed circles of triangles $\triangle ABM$ and $\triangle DCM$ meet at points $M$ and $E$. The line $EC$ intersects the circumscribed circle of $ABM$ second time in $F$, and lines $AF$ and $CD$ meet at $G$. Prove $EB=EC$ and that $F,M,G,C$ are concyclic.

[image]

I've only worked on $EB=EC$ as I assume that's a prerequisite to $F,M,G,C$ being proven to be concyclic. I think we might have to prove that $E$ has to be on line $AD$ as we know that since $\triangle EBC$ should be an isosceles triangle and $M$ is midpoint of $BC$ the angles $\angle EMC=\angle EMB=90$, but also we know that since $CDEM$ is an cyclic quadrilateral that $\angle EMC+\angle EDC=180$ and $\angle EDC=\angle CDA-\angle ADE$ so $\angle ADE=0$? Any help's appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Hint:

Prove that $\angle AFM= \angle DCM$ by considering their relationships with $\angle ABC$.

Comment: Thanks! I've figured this part out, how to go about proving $EB=EC$

Comment: Join $EM$. Prove that $\angle EMC=90^o$ and then $\Delta EMC \cong \Delta EMB$.

Comment: I'm aware of that, I mentioned it in my original post above, but isn't a prerequisite of that for $E$ to be on $AD$? How would one prove that? Can you elaborate?

Comment: (1) We can prove that $A, D, E$ are collinear by noting that $\angle AEM=180^o-\angle ABC$ and $\angle DEM=180^o-\angle BCD$.

(2) But I don't see why we need to prove this?

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks! We need to prove this because if $BCE$ is an isosceles triangle then it's height from $E$ would also be its' median and therefore $\angle EMC=90$ which means, from the fact that $EMCD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral that $\angle EDC+\angle EMC=180$ so $\angle EDC=90$ which is only possible if $A,D,E$ are colinear (because we know from the statement that $\angle ADC=90$)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have missed that. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you proved $EB = EC$ the second one follows easily from there (couldn't comment cause of low rep.). If $EB=EC$ notice that $E$ has to lie on $AD$ since we have $\angle EMC= \angle CDA=90$ (basically EC and EB will be the diameters of the circles). 
To prove points F, M, C, G are concyclic you can simply assign few angles to see it. Lets say $\angle EAF = \alpha, \angle EFA = \beta, \angle FCM = \theta$. Since $\angle DEC = \alpha + \beta$ and $\angle CEM = 90 - \theta$ angle $\angle DCM = 90 - \alpha - \beta + \theta$. Notice that angle $\angle GFM = 90 - \theta + \alpha + \beta$. Hence, those points are concyclic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The second part of the question seems pretty easy, it looks like the really hard part is proving $EB=EC$

Comment: You mentioned you worked on EB=EC, I thought you got that part. The first part is also straightforward as mentioned in above comment. Once you see E in on AD, EM becomes perpendicular to BC.

Answer (score 0):

We will make use of a couple of [corollaries to the Inscribed Angle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Applications).
One corollary says that a quadrilateral is concyclic iff opposite angles are supplementary. Another is [Thales' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem), which says that if the diameter of a circle is a side of an inscribed triangle, that triangle is a right triangle whose hypotenuse is the given diameter. Conversely, the hypotenuse of a right triangle is the diameter of its circumcircle.

---

Let $O_1$ be the circumcenter of $\triangle ABM$ and $O_2$ be the circumcenter of $\triangle MCD$.

Let $E$ be the intersection of the circumcircles of $\triangle ABM$ and $\triangle MCD$.

[image]

Since $A,B,M,E$ are concyclic,
$$
\angle AEM+\angle ABM=\pi\tag1
$$
Since $C,M,E,D$ are concyclic,
$$
\angle MED+\angle MCD=\pi\tag2
$$
Since $\angle ABM+\angle MCD=\pi$, $(1)$ and $(2)$ give
$$
\angle AED=\angle AEM+\angle MED=\pi\tag3
$$
That is, $A,E,D$ are colinear.

---

Since $\triangle EAB$ is a right triangle, $O_1$ is the midpoint of diameter $\overline{EB}$.
Since $\triangle EDC$ is a right triangle, $O_2$ is the midpoint of diameter $\overline{EC}$.

[image]

Since $\overline{O_1B}=\frac12\overline{EB}$ and $\overline{BM}=\frac12\overline{BC}$ and $\angle O_1BM=\angle EBC$, [SAS similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_(geometry)#Similar_triangles) says
$$
\overline{O_1M}=\frac12\overline{EC}\tag4
$$
Since $\overline{O_1M}=\overline{O_1B}=\frac12\overline{EB}$, $(4)$ implies
$$
\overline{EB}=\overline{EC}\tag5
$$

---

[image]

Since $A,B,M,F$ are concyclic, $\angle AFM+\angle ABM=\pi$. Furthermore, $\angle AFM+\angle MFG=\pi$. Therefore,
$$
\angle ABM=\angle MFG\tag6
$$
Furthermore, $\angle MCG+\angle ABM=\pi$. Therefore,
$$
\angle MCG+\angle MFG=\pi\tag7
$$
which says that $M,F,G,C$ are concyclic.

Comment: I could have put all the lines and points in [one image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTT0E.png), however, I thought it was a bit too crowded and not as clear.